# Logging the row in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

In an attempt to better understand tables for future use, I was hoping somebody could give me some simple syntax on the use of this method. I'm hoping to gain some understanding and build upon it in the future.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

So, I have this set up. Say I wanted to `NSLog` the contents of the row that was selected. How would I go about doing that?

Thus far, I've tried it my own way several times, however it either returns `nil` or I get an error.

**EDIT: Found it myself. Solution:**

```
NSLog(@"Row: %@", [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
```

Comment: Did you give it a try yourself? What happened?

Comment: When I tried what I thought MIGHT work, it ended up giving me nil every time.

Comment: Could you add that to your question? It would make it a lot easier to help and explain.

Comment: Sorry, I meant add the _code_ that you've tried to use. That will give answerers a little information that they'll need about the structure of your app.

Comment: Ah, I see. This isn't for an official app, I'm just working with a blank project trying to learn my way around tables. I've tried researching it as much as I can, but so far I haven't found anything. I'm just trying to fetch the contents of the cell and put them in the log

Comment: Figured it out myself; all is well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to answer this definitively without your actual code, but broadly:

This is a method in the [`UITableViewDelegate` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDelegate). The table view's delegate is an object that the table view essentially asks for its "opinion" about what to do when certain events happen, such as here, when the user taps on a row to select it.

Frequently, the delegate and the table view's [data source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) are the same object. The data source, as its name suggests, provides the data which the table view displays. It does this via methods that look a lot like the table view delegate methods; the table view *asks* the data source for the info as necessary, rather than the data source initiating the exchange.

So, somewhere this delegate/data source object (now we're coming to the part where it would be really helpful to have your own code to talk about) has a reference to a *model* that represents all the info that will be displayed in the table. This could be as simple as an array, or it could be a connection to a full-on database of some kind. In any case, the table view asks the data source to provide info for each row from that model -- this happens in [`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW6).

This method here, `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, can also access the model, so all you have to do to inspect the contents of the row is perform the same lookup as you do in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

As a concrete example:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [modelArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. I finally found your example at the very end a little while ago, but the extra detail is great. Thanks for the effort

Answer (score 4):

The indexPath has a category on it for dealing with tables. It responds to -row and -section.

```
NSLog(@"Row: %d , Section %d",[indexPath row], [indexPath section]);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I might have lead you to misunderstand. I want to log the contents, rather than the row number. Thank you though, it's very useful1